# Apache Pulsar - ACK exception

Tags: apache-pulsar

We have pulsar running for several weeks. A new persistent queue without partitions has been added.

Suddenly we are seeing exceptions as below. Only the new subscription is showing this behaviour. None of the other queues. All consumers are implemented in the same way as shown below. This is happening when the message is being acknowledged:

```
consumer.acknowledgeAsync(msg);
```

Exception:

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: recycled already
at io.netty.util.Recycler$WeakOrderQueue.transfer(Recycler.java:442)
at io.netty.util.Recycler$Stack.scavengeSome(Recycler.java:587)
at io.netty.util.Recycler$Stack.scavenge(Recycler.java:562)
at io.netty.util.Recycler$Stack.pop(Recycler.java:535)
at io.netty.util.Recycler.get(Recycler.java:162)
at org.apache.pulsar.common.util.collections.ConcurrentBitSetRecyclable.create(ConcurrentBitSetRecyclable.java:51)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.lambda$doIndividualBatchAckAsync$8(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:328)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.doIndividualBatchAckAsync(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:323)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.doIndividualBatchAck(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:294)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.doIndividualBatchAck(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:287)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.lambda$addAcknowledgment$4(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:235)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.addIndividualAcknowledgment(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:220)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.addAcknowledgment(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:232)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.addAcknowledgment(PersistentAcknowledgmentsGroupingTracker.java:196)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerImpl.doAcknowledge(ConsumerImpl.java:560)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerBase.doAcknowledgeWithTxn(ConsumerBase.java:688)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerBase.acknowledgeAsync(ConsumerBase.java:634)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerBase.acknowledgeAsync(ConsumerBase.java:619)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerBase.acknowledgeAsync(ConsumerBase.java:521)
at de.seepex.service.lastactive.PulsarLastActiveConsumer.messageListener(PulsarLastActiveConsumer.java:82)
at org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerBase.callMessageListener(ConsumerBase.java:1157)
```

Complete consumer method:

```
private void messageListener(Consumer<byte[]> consumer, Message<byte[]> msg) {
    try {
        byte[] payload = msg.getData();

        if (payload == null || payload.length == 0) {
            consumer.acknowledgeAsync(msg);
            return;
        }

        final LastActiveUpdate lastActiveUpdate = objectMapper.readValue(payload, LastActiveUpdate.class);
        lastActiveProcessor.process(lastActiveUpdate);


        consumer.acknowledgeAsync(msg);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("failed to process", e);
        consumer.negativeAcknowledge(msg);
    }
}
```

Any clues what might be causing the error?

Comment: It seems odd that you are doing a synchronous negative ack but the async (positive) ack. The method call
`consumer.acknowledgeAsync(msg);`
returns a `Future` so it should be handled something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705587/277023. I don't think it's contributing to your problem but the future should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a wrong netty version that was causing this bug:

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/discussions/21929